# To convert image with url into base 64 + android

Tags: java, android

How can I convert an image(with url) to base 64:

I tried following, but it did not work

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream("https://blahblah/xyz.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] bytes;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
bytes = output.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Got error at first try and catch. Can anyone suggest, what can be done?

Using  `new URL("https://blahblah/xyz.png").openStream()`, it crashes with following error:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Comment: Can you please also pubblish the stack trace?

Comment: `image(with url)`???? What is an image with an url?

Comment: Please add Error here.

Comment: The first part of your problem is that you cannot provide an URL to a `FileInputStream` use `new URL("https://blahblah/xyz.png").openStream()` instead for the rest check the other question

Comment: @greenapps - dont be in such a hurry, please see the question, i have clearly written: inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream("https://blahblah/xyz.png"));

Comment: Using new URL("https://blahblah/xyz.png").openStream(), it crashes with error : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: error is: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0):

First download the image from that given url, then using Bitmap convert it into byte array, then do the Base64 encoding.